# Como enviar uma variável recebida no método main para outra classe para ser tratada

Tags: java

Código:

```
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu();
    }

    private static void Menu() {
       CreateMatrix creatematrix = new CreateMatrix();
        int escalar = 0;
        int option = 0;
        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{                    System.out.println("       \n\n##################### Matrix Calculator –  ###################");
            System.out.println("\n                  ==============================================");
            System.out.println("                  |     1 - Add two matrices                     |");
            System.out.println("                  |     2 - Subtract Matrices                    |");
            System.out.println("                  |     3 - Scalar Multiplication of a Matrix    |");
            System.out.println("                  |     4 - Multiply two matrices                |");
            System.out.println("                  |     0 - QUIT PROGRAM                         |");
            System.out.println("                  ==============================================\n");
            System.out.print("\n");                        
                        option = op.nextInt();

                  switch(option){
        case 0:         
                        System.out.println("User Finished Program");
            break;
        case 1:

                        break;

        case 2:
                        System.out.println("Subtract Matrices");
                        chamarMatrizdivisao();
            break;
                case 3:
                        System.out.println("Scalar Multiplication of a Matrix");
            System.out.println("Digite o escalar: ");
                        escalar = op.nextInt();
                        break;

            case 4:
            System.out.println("Multiply two matrices");
                        chamarMatrizMultiplicacao();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option!!!");
        }
        }while (option !=0);
            System.out.println("Invalid value ou Program is being closed");
        }
    public static void chamarMatrizMultiplicacao(){
        Conteudo oConteudo = new Conteudo();
         List<String> lista = oConteudo.Matriz();
         oConteudo.MultiplicacaoMatriz22(lista);
    }
    public static void chamarMatrizdivisao(){
        Conteudo oConteudo = new Conteudo();
         List<String> lista = oConteudo.Matriz();
         oConteudo.DivisaoMatriz22(lista);
    }
}
```

Eu estou pedindo para o usuário digitar o escalar e quero levar essa variável para a minha classe e tratar no método que segue abaixo:

```
    public void EscalarMatriz22(List<String> conteudo){
       Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
       int[] NumerosMatrizesEscalar = new int[conteudo.size()];

       for (int ndxv = 0; ndxv < conteudo.size(); ndxv++) {
       try{
       int numv = Integer.parseInt(conteudo.get(ndxv));
       NumerosMatrizesEscalar[ndxv] = Integer.parseInt(conteudo.get(ndxv));
       } catch(Exception eox){
        }
        }
       int div11 = NumerosMatrizesEscalar[2] - NumerosMatrizesEscalar[9]; 

       int div12 = NumerosMatrizesEscalar[4] - NumerosMatrizesEscalar[10]; 

        int div21 = NumerosMatrizesEscalar[3] - NumerosMatrizesEscalar[11];  

        int div22 = NumerosMatrizesEscalar[5] - NumerosMatrizesEscalar[12]; 

        System.out.println(div11);
        System.out.println(div12);
        System.out.println(div21);
        System.out.println(div22);

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Não sei bem se entendi oque você quis dizer, porém você pode criar uma função dentro da class, porém fora do main, onde receberá a opção lida no main por parâmetro, fará o tratamento que você necessita e retornará true para caso tiver de acordo com oque você precisa ou false se não estiver de acordo.

Coloque uma variável booleana recebendo o retorno dessa função.

**Por exemplo:**

```
boolean resultado = nomeDaFuncao(int parametro);
```

Depois que tiver o resultado em mãos, você pode criar as condições da forma que quiser, por exemplo, uma mensagem de erro.

Por favor, se fugi muito da sua dúvida, me retorne melhor sua questão, para que eu possa te ajudar!

Comment: O que eu quero é pegar o que o usuário digitou nessa parte do código `case 3:
                        System.out.println("Scalar Multiplication of a Matrix");
            System.out.println("Digite o escalar: ");
                        escalar = op.nextInt();
                        break;` essa variável escalar eu quero levar para a outra classe do meu método `public class Conteudo {public void EscalarMatriz22(List<String> conteudo){
       `

Comment: Sua ideia é chamar essa função após ser lido o valor?

Você poderia modificar a função para passar mais um parâmetro, por exemplo:

public void EscalarMatriz22(List<String> conteudo, int escalar)

Seria essa a dúvida?

Comment: Isso mesmo, porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso, sempre dá erro no quando tento adicionar int escalar.

Comment: Você está alterando tanto na parte da criação da function, quanto na parte onde você chama a mesma? Se possível anexar o erro que te retorna, talvez eu consiga lhe ajudar.